# JSON Get Items by Value

Tags: javascript, json, key-value

What is the most efficient way to filter an JavaScript array of objects based on a key-value?

For example: I'd like to select items by color in the following array:

[{Id:1, color:"blue"},{Id:2, color:"green"},{Id:3, color:"blue"},{Id:4, color:"red"}]

There's an easy syntax for selecting items by property in languages like CSS or xslt, but I can't find an equivalent for JSON.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't filter JSON strings directly -- with ease, at least -- without first parsing them into JavaScript objects:

```
var collection = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

But note that JSON parsers are normally strict -- object keys must be strings (http://json.org):

```
[{ "Id": 1, "color": "blue" }, { "Id": 2, "color": "green" }, ...]
```

After that, you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the returned `Array`:

```
var filtered = collection.filter(function (item) {
    return item.color === "blue";
});

console.log(filtered[0]); // [Object] :: { Id: 1, color: "blue" }
```

To support older browsers, include [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) for `JSON.parse` along with the "Compatibility" code offered by MDN for `filter` (or use the [ES5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) for a collection of such definitions).

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "the compatibility code offered by MDN"?

Comment: @Christophe Sorry. I was referring to the code listed under the ["Compatibility" heading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not a language. I assume you mean javascript. And you will have to write it yourself there is no built in way.